# How to get rid of NUL characters in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

**The database**:
I have a Oracle11g database with a table that contains about 10 million rows and has about 40 columns. The data originates from punched card age and has been transformed from one Oracle version to the next several times. This is a live production database and in somewhat continuous use. But it's not so critical (especially during night time) that I could not strain it with expensive queries and updates. So that's ok.

edit: Charset is AL32UTF8.

**The problem**:
I noticed that some columns contain NUL characters. I have found values that consist of 1-4 NUL characters, but there can be in theory as many of them than the number of chars available for that column. I want to get rid of the NUL characters. If there are only NUL characters in the value, I want to change the column's value to SQL NULL. If there are NUL characters between other characters (I haven't though seen any cases) I want to remove them (replace with "").

**What I have tried**:

I have noticed that `select rawtohex(mycolumn) from mytable` returns for example '000000' (3 NUL characters).

`select rawtohex('A') from dual;` returns '61'

`select rawtohex('Ä') from dual;` returns 'C385'.

I have explored finding NUL characters like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mycolumn 
FROM mytable
WHERE rawtohex(mycolumn) LIKE '%00%;'
```

So far I haven't been able to find any columns that would contain any characters that's rawtohex would contain '00', except columns where there are only NUL characters. So it looks like using `LIKE '%00%'` is safe. But I'm uncertain of oracle implementation of rawtohex and what kind of hex coding it uses.

So... While I continue exploring this path and eventually write a script to fix the garbage, I'm asking if anyone has encountered this job before and how did you solve it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I'd use [`CHR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions026.htm#SQLRF00616) to identify the nul values. A nul is an ASCII 0 and `CHR()` will return the character representation of the number you pass in.

```
SQL> with the_data as (
  2  select 'a' || chr(0) || 'b' as str from dual
  3   union all
  4  select 'a' || 'c' from dual
  5         )
  6  select dump(str)
  7    from the_data
  8   where str like '%' || chr(0) || '%'
  9         ;

DUMP(STR)
----------------------------------------------------    
Typ=1 Len=3: 97,0,98
```

As you can see by concatenating percentage signs around `CHR(0)` (which is equivalent to nul) you can return rows with the nul in.

[`DUMP()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions055.htm#SQLRF00635) returns the data type ([1 means VARCHAR2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#BABCGCHG)) the length of the string in bytes and the internal representation of the data; the default is binary.

However, **you need to be careful with multibyte data** as `CHR()` returns the character equivalent of the modulus of 256 of the number:

```
SQL> with the_data as (
  2  select 'a' || chr(0) || 'b' as str from dual
  3   union all
  4  select 'a' || chr(256) || 'c' from dual
  5         )
  6  select dump(str)
  7    from the_data
  8   where str like '%' || chr(0) || '%'
  9         ;

DUMP(STR)
-------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=3: 97,0,98
Typ=1 Len=4: 97,1,0,99
```

As you can see you would mistakenly identify a nul here, using either `CHR()` or `DUMP()`

In other words, if you don't have multibyte data then the easiest thing do is simply [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions153.htm#SQLRF00697) it:

```
update <table>
   set <column> = replace(<column>, chr(0));
```

Utilising `RAWTOHEX()` has similar problems; though you can find the `00` there's no guarantee that it's actually a nul:

```
SQL> with the_data as (
  2  select 'a' || chr(0) || 'b' as str from dual
  3   union all
  4  select 'a' || chr(256) || 'c' from dual
  5         )
  6  select rawtohex(str)
  7    from the_data
  8   where str like '%' || chr(0) || '%'
  9         ;

RAWTOHEX
--------
610062
61010063
```

It actually has a further problem as well; imagine you had two characters `10` and `06` the returned value is then `1006` and you'll find `00`. If you were to use this method you have to ensure that you only looked at two character groups, from the start of the string.

As the internal representation of a nul character is used to represent parts of other, multibyte characters, you can't just replace them as you don't know whether it's one character or half a character. So, if you're using a multibyte character set you are, as far as I know, not going to be able to do this.

Comment: "if you're using a multibyte character set you are ... not going to be able to do this." Not all multibyte character sets. In UTF-8 (Oracle's AL32UTF8) any octet that is part of a multi-octet character will have the high bit set, making the numeric value of that octet greater or equal to 128. An octet with value 0 will be itself and not part of a larger character encoding.

Comment: The above was done on an AL32UTF8 database @Shannon. You're right, this won't hold true for _all_ multibyte character sets necessarily.

Comment: Thanks so far! I'll look into your answer, but it's most helpful. Charset of the database is AL32UTF8.

Comment: like '%' || chr(0) || '%' is good enough for me. I wrote a script (with Java) that searches the db for all rows that contain CHR(0). Then the script evaluates if the result row contents indeed contain NUL characters and executes the appropriate UPDATE statement.

Comment: A similar issue can also arise from using the NVARCHAR2 datatype, which internally separates each character by preceding it with a `00` raw character. For example, `AB` would appear as `00410042` when used with `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW`. To my knowledge, this cannot be fixed with `REPLACE(<column>, CHR(0))` (likely because of the datatype mismatch). I solved this problem by restructuring the table, since a VARCHAR2 field can be updated to values from an NVARCHAR2 one, implicitly casting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace function to remove **nul** char.

> Replace (FIELD, CHR(0), ' ')

After this **nul** value will be converted real **null**.

Best regards,